# Angular : bind query parameter to form field results in ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I created a simple directive which takes input from a queryparam and patches the value of a form input. The directive works fine, but I'm receiving this error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null'. Current value: 'testuser@test.be'`.

I searched for solutions on SO / Google and tried a few like putting the logic of ngOnInit of my directive in ngAfterContentChecked or ngAfterContentInit, but the error is still there...
**Can anybody point me in the right direction to solve this?**

Directive 'bindQueryParamToInput'

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[bindQueryParamToInput]'
})
export class BindQueryparamToInputDirective {
  @Input('bindQueryParamToInput') paramKey: string;

  constructor( private ngControl : NgControl) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

    if (queryParams.has(this.paramKey)) {
      this.ngControl.control.patchValue(queryParams.get(this.paramKey));
    }
  }

}
```

component.html in which the directive is used on email field

```
<div class="form-group" formGroupName="localAccountData">
    <label>Emailadres</label>
    <input formControlName="email"
           type="text" 
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Email (login)"
           bindQueryParamToInput="e">
</div>
```

component.ts where the form is initialized

```
@Component({
  selector: 'gimmi-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  registrationForm: FormGroup;

  constructor( ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registrationForm = new FormGroup ({
      'personData': new FormGroup({
        'firstName': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        'lastName': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        'birthday': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
      }),
      'localAccountData': new FormGroup({
        'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
        'password': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
      })
    });
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: The accepted solution works in the above scenario. But now I've put the email field in a separate component (the directive is now used in the subcomponent) and now the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` is back... :-(

I already tried to use the solution and add `this.ref.detectChanges()` in the ngOnInit of the subcomponent, but it didn't work...

**Is there something extra I need to do to solve this problem in the subcomponent?**

subcomponent email-input.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'email-input',
  templateUrl: './email-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./email-input.component.css']
})
export class EmailInputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() parentFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.parentFormGroup.addControl( 'email', new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]));
  }
}
```

subcomponent email-input.html (where the directive is used)

```
div [formGroup]='parentFormGroup'>
        <input  formControlName="email" 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Email (login)" 
                bindQueryParamToInput="e">
</div>
```

In the component.html, I only use the `<email-input></email-input>` component now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another "standard" solution would be imperatively ordering change detection.

```
  constructor( private ngControl : NgControl, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

    if (queryParams.has(this.paramKey)) {
      this.ngControl.control.patchValue(queryParams.get(this.paramKey));
      this.ref.markForCheck();

      // or, alternatively
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Only this solution works: this.ref.detectChanges(); 
Can you explain to me what this exactly does and how this is affecting my solution? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @bits In broad strokes, it's about child component's `ngOnInit` changing the parent's content, after the parent has already checked for changes, and `this.ref.detectChanges()` simply says "check again".

Comment: Ok thanks. I know have an extra issue: I've put the email field with the directive in a subcomponent of my form. Now I have the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError again and adding the solution in the subcomponent doesn't work :-( Check original question for more info. Can you please help me? @mbojko

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem I described in the edit by changing putting a `setTimeout` around the line that update form control value.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.ngControl.control.patchValue(queryParams.get(this.paramKey));
});
```

This works, but it feels like a workaround and not like a solid solution...
**So any help to get a better solution is much appreciated**